# Difference between PS1 optic drive models?

Tags: hardware, ps1

Old optic drive needs to be replaced, but I am unsure about the differences between the KSM-440ADM, KSM-440AEM, and KSM-440BAM models?

I have a SCPH-9001 unit that came with a KSM-440AEM, but is the BAM a more durable model, and would it even work? I can't seem to find a source where the differences are clear.